# Sublime Text mac shift-delete (backspace)

Tags: keyboard, backspace

In Sublime Text (2), I can't find the shift-delete that I had in BBEdit, where shift delete removes one character from the right of the cursor. I can't turn on this keyboard shortcut.

How can I do this in Sublime Text preferences files? I can't find the keybindings http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/key-bindings

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `CMD` + `Backspace` or `CMD` + `Shift` + `Backspace`